# How to type a Generic component in Vue 3's <script setup>?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, typescript-generics, vue-composition-api

I have a Select component that accepts an array of `options`. Each `option` can be an object of anything as long as it has the following attributes `id` and `text`

So I typed it like this:

```
type SelectOption<T> = {
  id: string | number
  text: string
} & T
```

But I'm not sure how to use this with `defineProps` and also `defineEmits` in the component.

```
defineProps<{
  options: SelectOption<??>
  modelValue: SelectOption<??>
}>()

defineEmits<{
  (event: 'update:modelValue', SelectOption<??>): void
}>()
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this, here's some related reading: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/3102 https://logaretm.com/blog/generically-typed-vue-components/ Long story short, it's not really possible right now.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon it 1 year later, it can be done now. See this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76233300/2380702

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is an updated answer to account for the recent improvements in this area :

- [Vue Language Tools has added support for generic types](https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/pull/2545)
- Support for generic components [has been added recently in Vue core 3.3](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#generic-components)

This allows you to write the following code (from the linked release blog post) :

```js
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends string | number, U extends Item">
import type { Item } from './types'
defineProps<{
  id: T
  list: U[]
}>()
</script>
```

Of course, this requires you to upgrade to the latest versions of vue and volar.

Note that as of writing this (May 2023), this feature is a bit rough around the edges but is still actively developed.

Comment: My code looks almost exactly like your example, but I get this error: `Property 'items' of exported interface has or is using private name 'T'`

Comment: I figured out that this happens if you declare the types of your props using an `interface`. The prop types must be literal.

Comment: Note that, as of Vue 3.3.4, generic components are still very buggy, unfortunately. Volar extension is also pretty bad at handling them.

Answer (score 4):

The approach I took worked in VS Code + Volar 0.40.13 and it also  works with Volar 1.0.0. (ensure you update your tsconfig.json file to include `"vueCompilerOptions.jsxTemplates": true`)

You first define the "non-generic" Vue component using a "non-generic" version of your type.

```
// MySelectBase.vue

type SelectOptionBase = {
  id: string | number;
  text: string;
  [key: string]: unknown;
}

defineProps<{
  options: SelectOptionBase[];
  modelValue: SelectOptionBase;
}>()

defineEmits<{
  (e: 'update:modelValue', v: SelectOptionBase): void
}>()
```

Then define the "Generic" version of the component.

```
<script lang="ts">
import MySelectBase from "./MySelectBase.vue";

export type SelectOption<T = {}> = {
  id: string | number
  text: string
} & T;

interface Props<T> {
  options: SelectOption<T>[];
  modelValue: SelectOption<T>;
}

type MySelect = new <T = {}>(props: Props<T>) => {
  $props: Props<T>;
  $emit: {
    (e: "update:modelValue", v: SelectOption<T>): void;
  };
};

export default MySelectBase as MySelect;
</script>
```

You can then use the `MySelect` component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import MySelect from "./MySelect.vue";

const item = ref<SelectOption<{ name: string; }>>();
const items = ref<SelectOption<{ name: string; }[]>>([
  { id: 1, text: "Johnny", name: "John" },
  { id: 2, text: "MJ", name: "Mary-Jane" },
]);
</script>

<template>
  <MySelect v-model="item" :options="items" />
</template>
```

When you hover over the `options` prop it should show `MySelect<{...}>.options: { id: number, text: string; name: string }`

Comment: While this answer has been incredibly useful in the past, generically typed components are now officially supported (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Use a default type value, so it doesn't have to be specified:

```
type SelectOption<T = Record<string, unknown>> = {
  id: string | number
  text: string
} & T
```

```
defineProps<{
  options: SelectOption[]
  modelValue: SelectOption
}>()

defineEmits<{
  (event: 'update:modelValue', value: SelectOption): void
}>()
```

In the end, your component should not know anything else about your `options`, except they have `id` and `text`.